# Moving from MySQL to MS Azure SQL Database

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I have a J2EE web application that issues parameterized SQL queries to a MySQL back-end. I need to replace the back-end with MS Azure SQL Database. I have migrated the DB and data over to MS Azure SQL Database. However all my queries from the app are failing. For example the following query (shown with the wrapping code) runs perfectly fine in the Management Studio but fails in the java code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM [mydb].[apps] WHERE [key] = ?;");
statement.setString(1, appKey);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

The error I get is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.
```

I tried various things like removing the [], qualifying the column name with the table name, etc. but nothing works.

Also one more question: The JDBC connection I am using string includes the database name (mydb) so I don't want to include it in each of my SQL statement. I never did for MySQL so I'd rather avoid doing it now since it would require me to manually add the DB name to each statement in the code. However if I remove the DB name from the above query it again fails with error `Invalid object name 'apps'`. Why isn't the DB specified in the connection string being used as the default one? The connection string I am using is `jdbc:sqlserver://{servername}.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydb;user={username}@{servername};password={password};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`

BTW I am using the Azure SQL Database V12 and connecting via Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server.

Comment: where Key = ?.. what should the ? indicate?

Also try removing the ';'

Comment: @NaguibIhab, ? is the placeholder where the next statement sets the value. Already tried after removing ";" but doesn't help.

Comment: This is a wild throw not sure if it will work, try this query: `SELECT * FROM apps WHERE key = 1`

Comment: The Microsoft 4.2 driver is still a "preview". Does this also fail if you use the 4.1 version of the driver?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, works fine with 4.1 version. However the DB name issue is still there.

Comment: In the expression `[mydb].[apps]` `mydb` is **not** the database, it's the *schema*. Unlike MySQL, SQL Server has two levels of namespace: database **and** schema. A fully qualified table name consists of three elements: `db_name.schema_name.table_name`. I guess you do not have a _schema_ named `mydb`. The default schema in SQL Server is usually `dbo`. So try `dbo.apps` instead. If the user you are using has a default schema defined, then you don't need the `dbo` either.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but my sample code ran fine. Per my experience, I think that the issue cause is by using incorrect table name form.

The MSSQL table name completed form is <db_name>.<owner_name>.<table_name>. Its short form could be <owner_name>.<table_name> or <table_name>. The item can be <item> or [<item>].

Sample Code (for Azure SQL Database, the same principle as MSSQL on Azure VM):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<host_name>:1433;database=<db_name>;";
//The completed connection string is jdbc:sqlserver://<host_name>:1433;database=<db_name>;user=<user like username@server_name>;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
        String user = "<user>";
        String password = "<password>";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = ?;" // My test table is 'person'
// The table name could be person, [person], dbo.person, [dbo].[person], <db_name>.dbo.person, [<db_name>].[dbo].[person]
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, "Peter Pan");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getLong("id")+","+rs.getString("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you to use the third-party Universal Database Management Tool "Dbeaver". It based on Eclipse and used JDBC Driver to connect kinds of Database include MSSQL. You can create db connection to MSSQL on Azure VM and test SQL queries.

Best Regards.